@DateTimeFormat not converting date while sending response
I have a Spring MVC application (Without Boot). I am using Spring MVC 6.
I am trying to learn @ResponseBody tag and I created an object of my bean class in the controller and sending it in the response.
The date element has been annotated with @DateTimeFormat annotation, but when sending the response, I am not getting it in the particular format.
User.java:
package com.habib.beans;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.util.Date;

public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double marks;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private Date dob;
    private Address address;

    public User(int id, String name, int age, double marks, Date dob, Address address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.marks = marks;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", marks=" + marks +
                ", dob=" + dob.toLocaleString() +
                ", address=" + address +
                '}';
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(double marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}


FirstController.java
package com.habib.controllers;

import com.habib.beans.Address;
import com.habib.beans.City;
import com.habib.beans.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

@Controller
public class FirstController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/first", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User first(ModelMap map) {

        User user =  new User(101,"Ali Asger Habib", 24, 98.54,
                new GregorianCalendar(2000, GregorianCalendar.MAY, 7).getTime(),
                new Address(23, "Fatehpura", new City("Udaipur", "Rajasthan", "India"), 313001));

        System.out.println(user);
        map.addAttribute("user", user);
        return user;
    }
}

I am getting the following response:
{
"id": 101,
"name": "Ali Asger Habib",
"age": 24,
"marks": 98.54,
"dob": 957637800000,
"address": {
"houseNo": 23,
"location": "Fatehpura",
"city": {
"cityName": "Udaipur",
"state": "Rajasthan",
"country": "India"
},
"pincode": 313001
}
}

I am not sure why DOB is not coming in the particular format.
I understand that using @JsonFormat can fix my issue but I want to why @DateTimeFormat is not working in this case.
Also, when I try using a view page in JSP, I still do not see it in the defined format but in the default format of the Date class.
Does @DateTimeFormat only work while parsing the request or does it work in both directions.

Since you're storing the place, it would be fine (and natural) to use LocalDate for DOB

java.time
In March 2014, the modern Date-Time API supplanted the error-prone legacy java.util date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to the modern java.time date-time API.
You use @DateTimeFormat with a date-time type parameter in your controller to inform the controller about the format in which the caller will send the date-time to it. @DateTimeFormat is a Spring annotation. Its typical use is to parse incoming date and time values from HTTP requests or to format date and time values when rendering views. You can find several tutorials on the internet (e.g. you can check this one) to understand it better.
You want to get the date-time string in the desired format in the response. For this, you should use @JsonFormat, a Jackson annotation for JSON serialization and deserialization. It informs the Jackson library to format your date-time object into a string data type with the specified format while producing the response in JSON e.g.
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate dob;

will produce a JSON response like
{
    "dob": "07/05/2000"
}

Learn about the modern date-time API from Trail: Date Time

Okay. Then would it be correct to say that @DateTimeFormat works only one way from request to Object and not the other way around.
PS: I am a beginner. My motive is not to run the code but to understand the fundamentals.

@AliAsgerHabib, @DateTimeFormat is a Spring annotation while @JsonFormat is Jackson annotation. The typical use of  @JsonFormat is for JSON serialization and deserialization. The typical use of @DateTimeFormat is to parse incoming date and time values from HTTP requests or to format date and time values when rendering views. So, both can work two-ways.

@DateTimeFormat vs @JsonFormat, nicely explained !

I think that your issue is related to the member of your class used for serialization in your case your field are private and getter are public so jackson will read attribute and value from getter and you place the annotation on your field try to move your annotation on your getter.
FYI :

you shoult avoir to use java.util.Date to represent time in nowday spring application you should use class from java.time package like Instant or ZonedDateTime
@ResponseBody annotation is now useless in your case if you annotated your Contraller with @RestController


JSON-supported property types are string, number, integer, object, array, boolean, and null. It doesn't support Date type. So in JSON. So, Spring will convert the date type to milliseconds and send a JSON response.
In this case, the date of birth is 2000-05-07 00:00:00 IST, which is 957637800000 milliseconds since epoch time.

In that case, @DateTimeFormat becomes useless doesn't it.

@DateTimeFormat will format the date at a Java class label. While converting to JSON, it will be changed to milliseconds.
